# Compare the last three or ... characters and find index in array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to compare if there is a certain string in each item and get the index of the list item.

Could someone help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] lista = {"item_100", "item_200", "item_300"};
        
        string input = "300";
        
        foreach(string i in lista)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        
        foreach(string i in lista)
        {
            string substr = i.Substring(i.Length - 3);
            
            if(substr == input)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nFound: {0}, index: ...", substr );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` you'll have the index of the array to work with.  Also you could do `lista[i].EndsWith(input)` instead.

Comment: You can use `for` loop instead `foreach`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use `[List<T>.FindIndex][1]` method:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] lista = {"item_100", "item_200", "item_300"};
        
        string input = "300";
        var index = lista.ToList().FindIndex(0, lista.Length, a=>a.Contains(input));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct what you asked, you can try using a `for` instead of a `foreach` to know the index, also if you want to check if the certain string in the item you should consider using the `Contains` function.
Example:

```
string str="Hello123";
Console.Write(str.Contains("123"));  //True
```